# What is the correct usage of the scp command in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scp

I am trying to retrieve some data from a remote directory (with an IP address) using the `scp` command in Windows Powershell. However, when I enter the command

```bash
scp -r root@<remote IP>:<remote directory>/file.txt/<local directory>
```

the data file is not saved. No error message is shown; only the scp usage message as shown in this screenshot is displayed:

[image: scp command usage message]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for `scp` is wrong - you have remote source and local target strung together into one path. They need to be separate parameters. Try this:

```
scp -r "root@<remote IP>:<remote directory>/file.txt" "<local directory>
```

One more thing to note: it looks like you're trying to copy just a single file from the remote. In that case you're not doing a recursive copy and don't need the `-r` flag.

Comment: Thanks! but now i get "An unknown error"

Comment: That's all it says?  "Unknown error"?  What are the remote and target paths you're using?

Comment: ssh: connect to host IPadress port 22: unknown error

Comment: That unfortunately is something between your client machine and the remote host...

Comment: Okay thank you !